# Pip install requirements.txt with -t for some libraries

Tags: python, pip

I have a pip `requirements.txt` file and I want to install only some of the requirement using -t mode.

For example `pip install boto3 -t .` works.

However when I specify in my requirements file `boto3 -t .`, and use `pip install -r requirements.txt`

I get the following error:

```
Usage: pip [options]
Invalid requirement: boto3 -t src
pip: error: no such option: -t
```

How can this be resolved?

Comment: As of today, the `-t, --target <dir>` option is not supported in `requirements.txt` files. The [section "_Requirements File Format_" of _pip_'s _User guide_](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#requirements-file-format) lists the currently supported options.